a phrase for describing "shaking hands"
Is there a phrase that describes a "handshake" when reaching an agreement? Where no paper was signed and the "handshake" represents the signing of the contract.

It's called a handshake deal.

OP - note that your phrase "Where no paper was signed and the "handshake" represents the signing of the contract." is incorrect, pls see my answer

It's called a gentleman's agreement (link to Wikipedia article)

A gentlemen's agreement, or gentleman's agreement, is an informal and legally non-binding agreement between two or more parties.

(link to usage chart)

It's potentially misleading to say the handshake (which isn't always part of the process) "represents the signing of the contract". I'm not a lawyer, but I wouldn't argue with Wikipedia's assertion that normally, any such informal agreements (without paperwork, signatures, and witnesses) are not legally binding.

A gentleman's agreement is just verbal, not written.

Exactly. My [spoken, oral] word is my bond.

Any agreement that has the elements of "Offer, Acceptance, Awareness, Consideration, Capacity and Legality"  can be legally binding, with or without paperwork, or even handshakes. Of course it can be hard to prove that these elements exist without the paper trail, but it's not correct to say that agreements without paperwork etc are not legally binding, because they are.

@JamesK: You'll note that I very specifically specified and italicised the word "normally". IANAL, but I know there's more to legal obligations than just bits of paper!

A gentleman's agreement is different from a handshake deal, generally. A handshake deal really is a kind of contract, where usually two people make a specific agreement about a particular thing. A gentleman's agreement often extends over a long time, and sometimes carries a suggestion that the reason it is not on paper is that it would not be enforceable and may not even be legal. For instance, price-fixing is often done by a gentleman's agreement. See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentlemen%27s_agreement.

@MarkFoskey: I already linked to and quoted from that Wikipedia page in my answer. If you think a "handshake deal" is something meaningfully different, that's your prerogative. (But it'll never stand up in court! :)

@JamesK Some types of contract cannot be formed by verbal agreement, however - in many places it's not possible to buy or sell real estate without a written contract, for example. Oral contracts can be binding, but not for all purposes. Some agreements that meet all the elements of a contract still aren't legally binding unless written down.

@FumbleFingers: If I walk into a store, pick something up, hand some cash to the cashier, and walk out, that is an oral contract for the sale of goods, and is perfectly valid (assuming I paid enough, the product was really for sale, etc.). Such contracts are probably agreed to millions of times per day, and might even outnumber written contracts (but written contracts of adhesion are also very common, so who knows).

@Kevin: Like I said, I'm not a lawyer. But I bet any money that over the years, many people have done exactly what you describe, and found themselves being prosecuted and convicted. Just because a shop sells things with price tags doesn't legally entitle you to "define" a legal sale without the explicit agreement and cooperation of the shop's representatives (sales staff). For all you know, the shop may be under a legal obligation to satisfy themselves that you are a "fit and proper person" to whom they can sell whatever you just walked out with. (Booze? Tobacco? Are you old enough? etc.)

I'm afraid to say this is quite wrong, indeed totally wrong.  A "gentleman's agreement" has no connection at all to a handshake deal. (Indeed, a gentleman's agreement has absolutely on connection to "deals" or contracts.)

The wikipedia article is total garbage, I'll go change it.

I'm afraid to report that even the wikipedia notes The essence of a gentlemen's agreement is ... honor .. [is not] in any way enforceable. It is distinct from a legal agreement or contract.

@NuclearHoagie  in many places it's not possible to buy or sell real estate without a written contract   That is a somewhat misleading statement and/or confusing statement. A business deal, contract, agreement (whether written or handshake, which means "not written") can be made over an agreement to sell something. You and I could form a firm written final agreement, written out by my sharp-ass lawyers, that you will buy my house from me for $X.  Actually transferring the house depends on complicated jurisdictional issues (example, Torrens Title in Australia) governed by govt's.

@FumbleFingers: You are nitpicking the "etc." in my comment. I put it there specifically to foreclose any nitpicking.

@Fattie I have no idea what you're getting at - "an agreement can be made over an agreement to sell something"? You seem to be confirming that you do indeed need a written contract to buy real estate - the final written agreement is all that matters, not the verbal discussions. In many places it is impossible to transfer legal ownership of a piece of property by verbal agreement. Oral real estate contracts are generally unenforceable - no matter how vigorously the buyer and seller verbally agree upon and accept the terms, it's not an enforceable contract.

? Right now, we could get a piece of paper saying "I, fattie, go agree to purchase property XYZ from Hoagster for $500,000, with transfer completed by 13th". That would be a contract.  This is completely commonplace. (That contract could be either written or verbal.)  However, this is completely outside the bounds of the question!  Cheers

It is also called handshake deal or agreement:

A “handshake deal” is an agreement between two (or more) parties to commit to an agreed business deal. It is a verbal commitment to a transaction.
For it to be considered legally binding, someone needs to witness the agreement take place and there must be some sort of written follow-up confirming the details agreed upon.


Yes, and one can actually say: We shook on it.

If

a contract,

or any sort of business arrangement,†

is enacted verbally,

rather than using a written contract,


it is referred to as a handshake deal.
In a word, "handshake deal" is a slangy synonym for "verbal agreement" or "verbal contract" or "unwritten contract".
Error in the description from the question:

"... where no paper was signed and the "handshake" represents the signing of the contract."

wrong on two counts.

The definition of a handshake deal is that no paper exists.

"The 'handshake' represents..." there is no physical handshake in a handshake deal. It has utterly nothing to do with a physical handshake, it's just a metaphor or slang.


{I've made a number of handshake deals over the decades, often very high value, and I've never literally "shaken hands" with anyone; people rarely literally shake hands on business deals, and you'd feel like an idiot if the other person said "Yuk yuk, let's literally shake on it" sort of thing. I've never, once, seen someone literally shake on either a written contract execution or a handshake deal. You sometimes see it on TV with presidents and treaties I guess.}

† Extremely common examples are talent-agent agreements, show biz agreements in the old days, and particularly company formation among friends (in many historic cases leading to large companies).

It seems pretty obvious Yahoo Finance consider handshake deal and gentlemen's agreement to be synonymous. Under the section title Donald Trump and the Art of the Handshake Deal in that link, it says Trump will often shake hands on a verbal gentlemen's agreement with another party.

...people rarely shake hands !!!??? Are we on the same planet?

"people rarely shake hands" sorry, in that clause of the sentence (like the others in the same sentence) I meant "people rarely literally shake hands on business deals".

Yahoo finance are idiots. : )
